# Vuetify Custom Dropdown | How to add a custom selection slot

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Trying to develop a custom Dropdown which currently looks like this:

[image: Custom Vuetify Dropdown]

You can't get it to look like that by default. I had to do some rework in the component and here is the code:

#### Component Code:

```
<template>
    <v-container fluid>
        <v-select :label="label" no-data-text>
            <template #selection> <p>Foobar</p> </template>
            <template #prepend-item>
                <div
                    v-for="([key, vals], $list) in Object.entries(options)"
                    :key="$list"
                >
                    <v-list-item
                        v-for="({ text, value: val }, $option) in vals"
                        :key="$option"
                        ripple
                        @mousedown.prevent
                        @click="toggle(key, val)"
                    >
                        <v-list-item-action>
                            <v-icon color="indigo darken-4">
                                {{ icon(key, val) }}
                            </v-icon>
                        </v-list-item-action>
                        <v-list-item-content>
                            <v-list-item-title>{{ text }}</v-list-item-title>
                        </v-list-item-content>
                    </v-list-item>
                    <v-divider class="mt-2"></v-divider>
                </div>
            </template>
        </v-select>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'LabspendMultiselect',
    props: {
        label: {
            type: String,
            default: 'Additional Filters',
        },
        selected: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => {},
        },
        options: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => {},
        },
    },
    methods: {
        icon(key, value) {
            if (this.selected[key] === value) return 'radio_button_checked';
            return 'radio_button_unchecked';
        },
        toggle(key, value) {
            this.$emit('selected', { key, value });
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

#### Parent Code:

```
<template>
// ...
         <v-row>
            <v-col>
                <custom-multiselect
                    :selected="additional_selections"
                    :options="additional_options"
                    @selected="setSelections"
                />
                <pre>{{ additional_selections }}</pre>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
// ...
</template>

<script>
    data() {
        return {
            additional_selections: {},
            additional_options: {
                hazmat: [
                    { text: 'HAZMAT', value: true },
                    { text: 'Not HAZMAT', value: false },
                ],
                expired: [
                    { text: 'Expired', value: 0 },
                    { text: 'Expiring Within 7 Days', value: 7 },
                    { text: 'Expiring Within 30 Days', value: 30 },
                ],
                depleted: [
                    { text: 'Depleted', value: 1 },
                    { text: 'Not Depleted', value: 2 },
                    { text: 'Below Threshold', value: 3 },
                    { text: 'Above Threshold', value: 4 },
                ],
            },
        };
    },
    methods: {
        setSelections({ key, value }) {
            this.$set(this.additional_selections, key, value);
        },
    }
</script>
```

This about does what I want it to do. However, there are some pain points.

For one, I can't add a [selection](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#slots-selection) slot. As you can see, I've added the slot in my code, but (should show the word Foobar) it doesn't appear and I believe it is because there is no `v-model` on the `v-select` tag.

Does anyone have thoughts on how to achieve this?

I'm looking to add the selections as a list like so:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was a bit too hacky to put everything in the `prepend-item` slot and not have any actual `items` or `v-model` on the v-select.

It's an interesting challenge for sure, adapting the v-select to handle groups of items, but I think it is easier to flatten everything into a single array while tracking the "group" each option belongs to programmatically

```js
computed: {
  selectionItems() {
    let items = [];
    let idx = 0;
    Object.values(this.options).forEach(group => {
      items.push(
        ...group.map(item => {
          return { ...item, groupIdx: idx };
        })
      );
      items.push({ divider: true });
      idx++;
    });
    return items;
  }
}
```

The computed property above creates the following array from your passed in options:

```json
[
  {text: 'HAZMAT', value: true, groupIdx: 0},
  {text: 'Not HAZMAT', value: false, groupIdx: 0},
  {divider: true},
  {text: 'Expired', value: 0, groupIdx: 1},
  {text: 'Expiring Within 7 Days', value: 7, groupIdx: 1},
  {text: 'Expiring Within 30 Days', value: 30, groupIdx: 1},
  {divider: true},
  {text: 'Depleted', value: 1, groupIdx: 2},
  {text: 'Not Depleted', value: 2, groupIdx: 2},
  {text: 'Below Threshold', value: 3, groupIdx: 2},
  {text: 'Above Threshold', value: 4, groupIdx: 2},
  {divider: true}
]
```

This can be set as the `items` prop of the v-select.  Other props `multiple`, `return-object` and `v-model` can also be added.  Similar customization that you had for each item can be added to `#item` v-slot.

```html
<v-select :label="label" no-data-text v-model="selection" multiple :items="selectionItems" return-object>
  <template #item="{ item }">
    <v-list-item ripple @click="select(item)">
      <v-list-item-action>
        <v-icon color="indigo darken-4">
          {{ icon(item) }}
        </v-icon>
      </v-list-item-action>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title>{{ item.text }}</v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
  </template>
</v-select>
```

Then the programmatic part with tracking the different groups comes into play in the `select` method called when clicking on any v-list-item. The new selected item must either replace another item belonging to the same group, else be removed if it already exists in the selection, else simply be added to the selection.

```js
select(item) {
const sameGroup = this.selection.findIndex(
    (s) => s.groupIdx === item.groupIdx && s.text !== item.text
  );
  // replace existing selected item if new selection is in same group
  if (sameGroup > -1) {
    this.selection.splice(sameGroup, 1, item);
  } else {
    const exists = this.selection.indexOf(item);
    // unselect an item if already selected
    if (exists > -1) {
      this.selection.splice(exists, 1);
    } else {
      // else add new selected item
      this.selection.push(item);
    }
  }
  this.$emit("selected", this.selection);
}
```

[working codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-2-forked-p1yp3z?file=/src/components/CustomMultiselect.vue)

I know the final result is now an array of objects which is not what you had before, but hopefully this still helps.

Comment: How did you come to know of `{divider:true}`? I cannot find a mention of it in the docs.

Comment: I'm confused by the `sameGroup` variable. So you are finding the same groupIndex but then comparing text? Why?

Comment: The `divider` property is documented on the [v-select API page](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-items) in the description for the `items` prop.  I compare the text because comparing just the group ID could result in a selected item matching itself (from a user unselecting an item).  Probably could've done that better now that I think about it by moving the conditional statements around (I just updated the codesandbox to do exactly that)